# Qualified vs. unqualified references

Tags: references

I'm having trouble finding out the difference between "qualified references" and "unqualified references" in regards to job searching.

Someone I know was recently let go due to budget cuts, and the boss was very fond of him. The boss offered to make calls, and give him "unqualified references".

In what way is a reference "unqualified"? I can only assume it's positive given the situation, but it sounds somewhat negative.

Any Google search I do only yields results specific to computer programming, which I'm already familiar with.

Comment: Excellent question. I too would have assumed "unqualified" referred to job performance or applicant suitability.

Comment: If you want a different perspective, you may find good help over at the [English Language & Usage SE site](http://english.stackexchange.com/). This question is really about an ambiguous use of English, not the workplace.

Comment: In this context, I'd interpret "unqualified" as  "endorsed with no caveats or reservations"

Comment: I have to agree with Vietnhi you are imposing qualified versus unqualified.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus - Yes, I was actually weighing these two SE's against each other. I've asked a few questions at EL&U in the past. Given the replies though, I don't think I was mistaken. The context, in my opinion, was very specific.

Comment: @Blam - Is qualified versus unqualified not implicitly imposed when using the "un-" prefix?

Comment: A qualified reference is a professional reference  from a person who can vouch for your qualifications for a job. A professional reference is typically a former employer, a colleague, a client, a vendor, a supervisor or someone else who can recommend you for employment. An unqualified reference would be a reference from your Uncle or your Grandparents or a Doctor, people you never worked with.

Comment: flagged, this should be in the english section, not really a "workplace" issue

Comment: @bharal - If the question was about what a "software framework" implies, would you not post it in a software SE instead of EL&U? Since this was related to references, the Workplace SE seemed like the most relevant option.

Comment: no offence, but the term is an english language idiom. it is more appropriate at the English site, as it is going to be searched for there, is easily tagged etc

Comment: I came here after watching an episode of TheGoodWife. Did you ask this question after watching that?

Comment: @kosmos - Bingo. I see now that I phrased the question as if that weren't the case. I probably figured the answers would be different if I revealed that the phrase was from a TV show.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In what way is a reference "unqualified"? I can only assume it's
>   positive given the situation, but it sounds somewhat negative.

In this context, "unqualified" means the same as "with no reservations".

Basically the boss is saying that he can recommend the laid off individual highly, without have to temper or qualify his praise.

It's clearly a positive. Nothing negative here.

Answer (score 3):

What I think he means is that he won't have any negatives or anything that might be construed as a negative. Often when someone gives references, they may "hedge" or use phraseology that is neutral, neither endorsing nor disapproving of the person.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your local meanings. You never said where you're from.

Where I live (Germany) an unqualified reference is a reference that just states facts. Where you worked, which position you held, start and enddate. A qualified reference also includes your qualities i.e. how good you were at the job, what exactly you did, if you were a good team player or if you had problems with colleagues. Your negotiation skills with customers, virtually anything that has any relevance to the job you did. A qualified reference will tell people how *good* you are at the job you did.

You are entitled to one type of reference of your choosing in Germany. Most people will assume that if you put up an unqualified reference, the qualified one would have been mostly negative.

Answer (score -1):

Is this from the good wife? 
The context is out of place!
Because “unqualified” almost sounds like they are giving a reference for a position that one isn’t fully capable of performing, without additional assistance.
Unqualified reference means “without reservations”..